# Nokia Maps - Here Cluster - Add together values from different points

Tags: javascript, markerclusterer, here-api

I have a set of values like this ones:

...

```
[
 {
  "LATITUDE": "40.1733",
  "LONGITUDE": "-85.4786",
  "EVENT_ID_COUNT": "2"
 },{
  "LATITUDE": "40.1733",
  "LONGITUDE": "-85.4786",
  "EVENT_ID_COUNT": "5"
 }
]
```

Nokia Maps identify each record from this json as only one marker, but, what I need is to show the "EVENT_ID_COUNT" value, and add together them.

For example, if I am out, I should see one marker with value "7", but when I zoom in, I should see two markers, where one of them has "2" and the other "5"

This behavior helps me to have 100K markers, but only show 3K because several of them come from the same place.

The code:

```
....
function ZoomToTheme(){

            var baseTheme = new nokia.maps.clustering.MarkerTheme();
            this.getClusterPresentation= function(dataPoints){
                var cluster = baseTheme.getClusterPresentation(dataPoints);     
                cluster.$boundingBox = dataPoints.getBounds();
                return cluster;
            }
            this.getNoisePresentation = function(dataPoint){
                var noisePoint = baseTheme.getNoisePresentation(dataPoint);
                noisePoint.$text = dataPoint.text;
                return noisePoint;
            }
        }

        function addZoomToListener(map){
            map.addListener("click",  function(evt) {
                if ( evt.target.$boundingBox !== undefined){
                    evt.display.zoomTo(evt.target.$boundingBox, false);
                    $("#ticker").text("");
                } else if ( evt.target.$text !== undefined){
                    $("#ticker").text(evt.target.$text + " noise point was clicked.");
                }
            } );
        }
....
data.forEach(function(d, index) {
            if(d[mapOptions.count]){
                dataPoints.push({
                    latitude : d.latitude,
                    longitude : d.longitude,
                    text : d.count
                });
            }
        }, this);
...
this.clusterProvider = new nokia.maps.clustering.ClusterProvider(
                this.map,
                {
                    eps: 16,
                    minPts: 1,
                    dataPoints: dataPoints,
                    theme : new ZoomToTheme()
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the event count to each of the data points as 'weight' property (https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-clustering-datapoint.html). The result will be that they get counted together during the clustering. After the clustering operation your clusters should have the combined weight (https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-clustering-icluster.html). Use getWeight on the result to get the combined weight within a cluster...

Comment: Sorry to mension it to late. I am using Nokia Maps 2.5 :(

Comment: It's almost the same. Adding a dar point allows to pass a 'value' property as part of the data point itself (https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.clustering.IClusterPoint.html)...

Comment: As I understood, the weigth is not to show a value, is just to center the marker that group a set of markers.